# Why does OS X Snow Leopard have two hosts files?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, hosts-file

I noticed that OS X has two hosts files: /private/etc/hosts and /etc/hosts. What is the difference between them?

I was attempting to modify my iMac's hosts file in Terminal and tried the usual `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts`, but that brought up an empty page. I thought the hosts file was simply empty. I added the entries I wanted to block and when I tried to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, I got the error "No file exists".

After some researching, I tried using `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and it brought up what looks like the hosts file (the same entries as I have on my MBP running the same OS when I run `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts`).

Is there a difference in the file in `/private/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hosts`? Does that mean I have a problem with my iMac's hosts file?

Comment: `/etc` is symlinked to `/private/etc` (open Terminal and type `l -l /etc`) so I'm also confused with what you report. Are you sure you edited `/private/etc/hosts` and not `/private/etc/host` (which is what you get with tab expansion and doesn't exist)?